# Incorrect Dynamic Libraries linking after explicit set in Cmake

Tags: linux, matlab, boost, cmake, ros

I've got a very frustrating issue a the moment.  I'm attempting to build an executable that uses ROS and a compiled Matlab .so file.  Due to what I believe is a boost conflict, I'm trying to build this exe using an earlier version of boost.  Now, I've set up the cmakelist file, ran catkin_make (as its a ros project) and everything compiles, and the correct boost version is seen.

However, when running a ldd on the compiled exe, it still seems to be linking to the more recent version.  Its rather annoying.   I've posted the cmakelists file, and the ldd outcome.  My system is Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo.

Any help would be really good, as I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out what is wrong!

Many thanks in advance!

```
##CMAKE FILE

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(testmatlabdll)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wfatal-errors -O4 -march=native")
add_definitions(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED)

find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED)
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
set(BOOST_ROOT /home/devbot/Downloads/boost_1_50_0)
set(BOOST_DIR /home/devbot/Downloads/boost_1_50_0)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /home/devbot/Downloads/boost_1_50_0)
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /home/devbot/Downloads/boost_1_50_0)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)

message(STATUS "BOOST_ROOT = ${BOOST_ROOT}")
message(STATUS "Boost_VERSION = ${Boost_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Boost_LIB_VERSION = ${Boost_LIB_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Boost_MAJOR_VERSION = ${Boost_MAJOR_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Boost_MINOR_VERSION = ${Boost_MINOR_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES = ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS = ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS REQUIRED
              system filesystem thread date_time iostreams serialization chrono)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_generation image_transport cv_bridge)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp
                              std_msgs
                              pcl_ros
                              sensor_msgs
                              cv_bridge
                              message_runtime
               LIBRARIES      ${PROJECT_NAME}
               DEPENDS        system_lib)


include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

include_directories(/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/extern/include/)
include_directories(/opt/matlab/extern/include)
include_directories(/home/devbot/catkin_ws/src/testmatlabdll/src)
link_directories(/home/devbot/catkin_ws/src/testmatlabdll/src)

add_library(mwmc SHARED IMPORTED) 
set_property(TARGET mwmc PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v82/runtime/glnxa64/libmwmclmcrrt.so)

add_executable(testMatlab src/testMatlab.cpp)

target_link_libraries(testMatlab ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES}  ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(testMatlab roughlib mwmc)
```

### OUTPUT FROM LDD

```
ldd testMatlab | grep boost
    libboost_system.so.1.50.0 => /home/devbot/Downloads/boost_1_50_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.so.1.50.0 (0x00007f7456f8a000)
    libboost_system.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0 (0x00007f7454662000)
    libboost_thread.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0 (0x00007f745444c000)
    libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0 (0x00007f7454018000)
    libboost_regex.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so.1.54.0 (0x00007f744d5d8000)
```

Comment: What's the entry for BOST_LIBRARY in your CMakeCache.txt file? Is this right?

Comment: Hi, Boost_LIBRARY_DIR = my downloaded boost 1.50.0, but the INCLUDE_DIR = usr/include.  Looking at the found libraries in a message from building the project seems to state everything found is 1.50.0.  I can post the output from the build command if it would help?

Comment: Delete the cache and re-configure. Still the wrong Boost include path? Then maybe some other library tries to use Boost. Move finde_package(Boost ..) up to be the first test performed.

Comment: Maybe related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33230616/boost-update-issue-with-my-code).

Comment: Hi there, that seems to have done it.  It appeared that PCL was requiring boost and therefore loading it up first.  It seems to then ignore my request for a specific version of boost.  I put FindBoost first, and it seems to have solved it.

Comment: @dezweb: Would you please be so kind and answer your own question and accept your answer? This way the question no longer looks unanswered. Or if you think it is not helpful for others, close the question.